# C# .NET Interface implementation at multiple levels

Tags: c#, .net, generics, inheritance, interface

I found myself digging into System.Collections.Generic when using a BindingList. I don't understand something about the following interface implementations:

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
public interface ISet<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

Why does

```
ISet<T>
```

Implement

```
IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
```

when ICollection already does? Wouldn't the following be acceptable?

```
public interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerable
public interface ISet<T> : ICollection<T>
```

Any help understanding this is much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What source are you looking at? https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/iset.cs

Comment: Look at the source code: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/iset.cs,85e59789e1cf992f - It's just Visual Studio that's showing you all interfaces in the hierarchy

Comment: Microsoft likes repeating inherited interface declarations, it is excellent self-documentation.  It makes no difference whatsoever to the code or the runtime behavior.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant, your comment was the nice, concise answer I was really looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have the interface declarations from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd412081(v=vs.110).aspx) or another documentation source. While it is right that `ISet<T>` does not have to explicitly implement `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerable` as you can see in the [reference implementation](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/generic/iset.cs) ...

```
public interface ISet<T> : ICollection<T>
```

... documentations still contain the complete list as a convenience for the developer so they know what interfaces are implemented by `ISet<T>` even if only through inheritance. Going through a possibly long inheritance hierarchy would probably not enhance the benefit of such a documentation.

Comment: I figured this was a convenience/readability feature but thought I'd ask the community. Thanks @Adrian!